# Converting the date of one of the columns of a selected table

Tags: sql, date, select

I can't seem to get this right. I am currently trying to convert one of the columns to a different date format, but my code is not working.

The current format of TrackingNumbers.ShipDate is "MM/DD/YYYY  hh:mm:ss AM/PM", and I am trying to make it convert it to "yyyy-mm-dd".

```
SELECT TOP 500 -- Selects the first 500 records for a smaller file
    Orders.PONum AS 'order-id',
    TrackingNumbers.TrackingNumber AS 'tracking-number',
    TrackingNumbers.Gateway AS 'carrier-code',
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), TrackingNumbers.ShipDate, 120) AS 'ship-date', 
            -- The date format is currently "MM/DD/YYYY  hh:mm:ss AM/PM"
            -- It needs to be yyyy-mm-dd
    CASE TrackingNumbers.ShippingMethodID   -- Converts the shipping Methods so customers can understand them
        WHEN '900' THEN 'USPS Priority (2-14 days)'
        WHEN '103' THEN 'UPS 2nd Day Air'
        WHEN '108' THEN 'UPS Ground'
        WHEN '112' THEN 'UPS Worldwide Expedited'
        WHEN '214' THEN 'USPS Express Mail Intl'
        WHEN '220' THEN 'USPS Priority (2-14 days)'
        WHEN '505' THEN 'UPS Next Day Air Saver'
        WHEN '207' THEN 'USPS First ClASs (7-30 Days)'
        WHEN '222' THEN 'USPS Express Mail Envelope'
        WHEN '102' THEN 'UPS Next Day Air'
        WHEN '217' THEN 'USPS Priority Mail International'
        WHEN '107' THEN 'UPS 3 Day Select'
    END AS 'ship-method'
FROM
    TrackingNumbers, -- Selects two different tables
    Orders  
WHERE 
    Orders.OrderID = TrackingNumbers.OrderID -- Merges Orders with tracking numbers
    AND 
    Orders.PONum<>'' -- Only grabs orders with a PO number
Order By 
    TrackingNumbers.ShipDate Desc -- Sorts by descending ship date of the package (order ship date can be different)
```

The 5th line is where the trouble is at. How is it supposed to be formatted?

Comment: Are you sure this field has datetime type?

Comment: Yes, the field is DATETIME.

Comment: So, what's the problem? What result do you receive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx), ANSI style (yyyy-mm-dd) in the CONVERT function would seem to be 102 style, not 120, unless I am mistaken.

How about:

```
REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), TrackingNumbers.ShipDate, 102), '.', '-') AS 'ship-date'
```

Comment: Hmmm, this made the SQL code work but it's still exporting as 12/13/2012. I tried 102 and 120 but still no luck.

Comment: Nevermind, it was an excel display problem. I opened it in Notepad++ and it's the correct format.

Comment: @JackCole Excellent, glad to be of help. :)